# How to use ListView BELOW LinearLayout

Tags: android, css, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I'm trying to make MyProfile activity in my android project. In MyProfile activity  the first screen will show My Profile Pic along with my name and other Bio data about user. I want to make the screen/layout swipe able such that if i swipe the screen up, my current info is pushed up and a list view appears that will show user's posts.

I'm not sure if this is possible or not because I'm using Nested Layouts to accomplish the first screen idea with Layoutwidth and Height being set to the screen width and height from java code.

Here is my XML code

```
        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:background="#c0c0c0"/>

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/touch"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/mynumofposts"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="200"/>
    </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:background="#c0c0c0"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:src="@drawable/nearbycircle"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/mynumoffollowers"
                android:text="300"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/myprofilelist"/></LinearLayout>
```

Now I want to use this ListView at the bottom to show user's posts but I can't implement the swipe up and show list in my app.

I've checked the other similar questions but nothing familiar to my problem.

This is what I've achieved so far and now i want to make the Layout swipe able and show a ListView [image]

Comment: set first position of your list as empty transparent view, calculate height that you need from java, ( depend on height of screen might be different ) then set that to first position and set other data from second position. ( if i get your mean )

Comment: Hard coding the height might be a problem for some devices because some mobiles have small displays and others have large screens.. don't you think it will be a problem? And how to make the positions in xml? can you please make the edit in code?

Comment: you can get height of screen, then set your empty view in sample 80% , you can't do this from xml you must do that in code, check position in `getView` in adapter ( `onCreateViewHolder` in recycle ) if it's 0 then show empty view, else show list.get(position-1)

Answer (score 1):

You May Use A **ScrollView** and Inside that ScrollView Use the Your Current Layout For Profile And A Listview

Just Like This One

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView" >
    <include android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        layout="@layout/your_current_layout_for_profile_without_list_view" />
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView" />
</ScrollView>
```

Or Use this layout (modified by using your provided xml)

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:background="#c0c0c0" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:src="@drawable/touch" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mynumofposts"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="200"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:background="#c0c0c0" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:src="@drawable/nearbycircle" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mynumoffollowers"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="300"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/myprofilelist"/>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a **RecyclerView** of the ListView, with 2 view types, first view type for item at index 0 is where you would load your LinearLayout, and any other index will be of type post for the items in your list view

Answer (score 0):

This can be done.

Have you layout for MyProfile.java activity like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <FrameLayout
         android:id="@+id/content_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
</LinearLayout>
```

After this have two different fragment

> `MyProfileFragment` -- this will contain  Bio data about user, make sure this is the `Fragment` you load first when you start your `MyProfile` activity
>
> `MyListFragment`    -- this will contain the list you want to show

get the event in the `MyProfile.java` activity relevant to swipe up and down and use this xml to show the up and down animation.

```
  MyListFragment fragment = new MyListFragment();
    final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    final FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fragment_slide_up_enter, R.anim.fragment_slide_down_exit)
                .replace(R.id.content_main, fragment, "place")
                .addToBackStack("FRAGMENT_TAG")
                .commit();
```

use following xml which you would save in `res/anim` directory in your android project

> fragment_slide_down_exit.xml

:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:fromYDelta="-1000" android:duration="1500"/>
</set>
```

> fragment_slide_up_enter.xml:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:fromYDelta="1000" android:duration="1500"/>
</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ::Collapsing Toolbar Layout
Here's one example link for tht: [CollapsingToolbarLayout](https://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/)

For Google details on ::[CollapsingToolbarLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html)